# Using generic linked list but forced to use (cast) when popping

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, stack

I am deliriously overjoyed to say that I just implemented a generic linked list from a few weeks ago in a project and *IT WORKS*! One problem, though. I am **forced to do a cast** (and didn't expect to).

Here are some snippets, I hope enough to define problem, starting with the generic stack:

```
    public class GenericStack<E> {

      public LinkedList <E> stack = new LinkedList<>();

      public void push (E obj){
        stack.add(obj);
      }

      public E pop() {
        if (stack.isEmpty()) return null;
        return stack.removeLast();
      }
      ...
}
```

Here's the class defintion in which I use the generic stack:

```
public class Grid extends GenericStack<JTextField> implements ActionListener, KeyListener, KeyCodes
```

Here's me defining `stack` and what I'm pushing and popping:

```
  GenericStack stack = new GenericStack();
  public static JTextField[][] cells = new JTextField[11][11];
```

Here's me pushing onto `stack`:

```
 stack.push(Grid.cells[currentCell.row][currentCell.col]);
```

Here's where I pop from `stack,` which works ONLY IF I DO THE CAST shown:

```
  private void calculate(){
    JTextField w = new JTextField();
    while(stack.size()>0){
      w =  (JTextField) stack.pop();
      System.out.println("stack element " + w.getText());
    }
  }
```

Now I'm not complaining; I'm not even sure there's a problem to deal with, but without the cast `(JTextField)`, I get "*INCOMPATIBLE TYPES--REQUIRED: JTextField; FOUND: Object*" but `stack.pop()` is clearly defined to return the generic type, which is `JTextField`, so why do I need to cast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
GenericStack stack = new GenericStack();
```

That's using the *raw type* of `GenericStack`. It's not clear why you've got this at all when you've already extended `GenericStack<JTextField>` to be honest. I'd expect you to *either* use composition:

```
public class Grid implements ActionListener, KeyListener, KeyCodes {
    private final GenericStack<JTextField> stack = new GenericStack<JTextField>();

    private void calculate() {
        while (stack.size() > 0) {
            JTextField w = stack.pop();
            System.out.println("stack element " + w.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

*or* use inheritance:

```
public class Grid extends GenericStack<JTextField> 
    implements ActionListener, KeyListener, KeyCodes {

    private void calculate() {
        while (size() > 0) {
            JTextField w = pop();
            System.out.println("stack element " + w.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment you're mixing the two, which is really odd.

Answer (score 1):

You have used raw type of your generic type in the following instantiation:

```
GenericStack stack = new GenericStack();
```

When you use raw types, all the generic type inside the class is replaced by their raw type counterpart, and the type parameters are replaced by their erasures. Since erasure of `E` in your case is `Object`, as it doesn't have any bound. So, the linked list, and methods:

```
public LinkedList <E> stack = new LinkedList<>();
public void push (E obj) { ... }
public E pop() { ... }
```

will be erased to:

```
public LinkedList stack = new LinkedList();
public void push(Object obj) { ... }
public Object pop() { ... }
```

hence, you get back `Object` type, when you invoke `pop()` method.

What you need is a *parameterized instantiation*:

```
GenericStack<JTextField> stack = new GenericStack<>();
```

And of course, what JonSkeet said in his answer. Don't mix-up inheritance and composition. You are having a reference of type `GenericStack`, and also extending it. It doesn't make sense. Follow the advice in Jon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

***D'OH!!***

So happy it worked I overlooked a few obvious (to experienced folk) things (that I truly have no excuse for overlooking), so yes, I made the change Rohit Jain suggested (after noting same from Jon Skeet) and I've got a sleeker method of popping:

```
  private void calculate(){
    while(stack.size()>0){
      System.out.println("stack element " + stack.pop().getText());
    }
  }
```

*(Method's called `calculate` because it's GOING TO do so soon.)*

But, Jon, I don't see how my code indicates that I'm mixing composition and inheritance, but maybe that's because I don't fully understand either just now!

I'll tell ya this, though: the daily (day-long??) frustration just to get one more line of code to work are *over*. Java ***rocks!*** (once you get to a certain point on the learning curve!) I'm stunned at how far I've come on this in just a couple of days! (OK, maybe coffee helped!)

Comment: You can mark one of the answers as accepted. Regarding the confusion of composition and inheritance, we thought, your declaration of `GenericStack` is inside the `Grid` class. If it isnt' then it's fine.

Comment: I was typing as Rojit posted a second time. That's a great explanation since erasure had reared its head a day or two ago and I just decided to wait until later. Well, it's later and I think I got it. THANKS. But now I have to again try to come to grips with the 'duplication' since now both of you guys have mentioned it. I'll get it, maybe even today. And I just re-read both posts. I may have it even as I type. THANKS again.

Comment: I GOT IT! I removed the extends clause and, of course, it worked. I didn't realize (didn't think) that, with GenericStack being part of the same package, extends is redundant. But note: one reason extends was there in the first place was that I was HOPING to import genericstack, but I couldn't make it work, so I gave up and just copied the genericstack package into the current one. (I guess I'll go back to trying to import, since that IS pretty important to be able to do, especially with one's own class!)

Comment: NOW I REALLY have it: stack WAS declared as GenericStack<JTextField> INSIDE Grid class constructor WITH EXTENDS GenericStack<JTextField> on class statemen. Now it's declared inside MAIN, where I WANTED it to be in the first place, but it wouldn't compile, so I moved it to the constructor, for no good reason. NOW with stack declared IN MAIN AND with EXTENDS in the class statement, I think I'm clear on where you guys were coming from--the other option being NO EXTENDS AND DECLARE STACK WITHIN GRID class. Scope and visibility were eluding me, among other things.